# Computing the integral of a certain surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, differential-forms, surface-integrals

I am given the surface $$S:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\cosh 2z,z\in[0,1]\}$$
They ask me to find a parametrization for this surface of revolution. This corresponds to the following $$\varphi(u,v)=(2\cosh(2u)\cos(v),2\cosh(2u)\sin(v),u)$$ with $(u,v)\in[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$. With this, they ask me to compute the integral over the 2-form $\omega=(z^2+2z)dx\wedge dy+(2x+2yz-z)dx\wedge dz$ if our surface is oriented by the normal vector $\nu(2,0,0)=(-1,0,0)$. Since $\varphi(0,0)=(2,0,0)$, $\varphi_u(0,0)=(0,0,1)$ and $\varphi_v(0,0)=(0,2,0)$, we have that $\nu(0,0)=\varphi_u(0,0)\wedge\varphi_v(0,0)=(-2,0,0)$ and thus we have chosen the correct orientation. Now, $$\int_{S}\omega=\int_{[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]}\varphi^{*}((z^2+2z)dx\wedge dy+(2x+2yz-z)dx\wedge dz)$$
To compute the pullback we do the following $$(u^2+2u)d(2\cosh(2u)\cos(v))\wedge d(2\cosh(2u)\sin(v))+(4\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+4u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-u)$$ $$d(2\cosh(2u)\cos(v))\wedge du$$ $$= 4(u^2+2u)(2\sinh(2u)\cos(v)du-\sin(v)\cosh(2u)dv)\wedge (2\cosh(2u)\cos(v)dv+4\sin(v)\sinh(2u)du)+2(4\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+4u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-u)(2\sinh(2u)\cos(v)du-\sin(v)\cosh(2u)dv)\wedge du$$ $$=4(u^2+2u)(4\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)\cos(v)^2 du\wedge dv + 4\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)\sin(v)^2 du\wedge dv)+2\sin(v)\cosh(2u)(4\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+4u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-u)du\wedge dv$$ $$=16(u^2+2u)\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)du\wedge dv+2\sin(v)\cosh(2u)(4\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+4u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-u)du\wedge dv$$

But this seemes a super long process, plus I don't really know if I will be able to integrate the expression. Is there a simpler way? Like using Stokes theorem or so?

Comment: Compute the derivative as required by Stokes' theorem. What does it simplify to? And how could you leverage its simplicity even though your surface of revolution is not enclosed?

Comment: $d\omega=(2z+2)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz-2z dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=2 dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$. Now, Stokes Theorem tells us that $$\int_{\partial S}\omega=\int_{S}d\omega$$ How do I use this last theorem to find my result?

Comment: If you attempt to answer my second question, you will answer yours. If you get stuck feel free to ask for another hint.

Comment: I guess, but I want to compute $\int_{S}\omega$ right? Instead of $\int_{\partial S}\omega$. I also find difficult uderstanding what is $\partial S$ in my example.

Comment: Hint: The integral you have been asked to compute only forms a part of $\partial S$ in the Stokes' theorem evaluation.

Comment: This make me even more confused. I geniunely don't understand what I have to do. How do I have to know that this is a part of $\partial S$ if I don't understand what is $\partial S$ on the first place?

Comment: Since $d\omega$ is a $3$ form, the "$S$" in Stokes' theorem would have to be a segment of a $3$ manifold (which I will denote $\Omega$), in this case a nontrivial portion of space embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$. The problem does not tell you what this $\Omega$ has to be because you are free to choose an infinite number of these shapes. Your surface right now has a nontrivial boundary $\partial S$ right? But $\partial (\partial \Omega)$ must be trivial. In order to rectify this you have to glue on extra surfaces $S_i$ such that $\partial S_i = \partial S$ such that $\partial(S_i\cup S) = \emptyset$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Now that I have answered my own question, could you please explain your method and what you meant? If you post an answer I will tick yours as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: I am disappointed you chose to be disrespectful. This is a textbook [Divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) calculus problem for first year calculus students, perhaps you should try to learn those basics before you attempt something as advanced as differentiable manifold theory.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer my own question using brute-force, i.e. integrating as usual. We have, $$4(u^2+2u) d(\cosh(2u)\cos(v))\wedge d(\cosh(2u)\sin(v))+(8\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+8u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-2u) d(\cosh(2u)\cos(v))\wedge du$$ $$=4(u^2+2u)(2\sinh(2u)\cos(v)du-\sin(v)\cosh(2u)dv)\wedge (2\sinh(2u)\sin(v)du+\cos(v)\cosh(2u)dv)+(8\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+8u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-2u)(-\sin(v)\cosh(2u)dv)\wedge du$$ $$=4(u^2+2u)(2\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)\cos(v)^2du\wedge dv+2\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)\sin(v)^2du\wedge dv)+\sin(v)\cosh(2u)(8\cosh(2u)\cos(v)+8u\cosh(2u)\sin(v)-2u)du\wedge dv$$ $$=8(u^2+2u)\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)du\wedge dv+8\sin(v)\cos(v)\cosh(2u)^2du\wedge dv+8u\cosh(2u)^2\sin(v)^2du\wedge dv-2u\sin(v)\cosh(2u)du\wedge dv$$

Now we have to compute $$\int_{S}\omega=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\star)$$ where $(\star)$ corresponds to the last expression. This can be split like the following, $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}8(u^2+2u)\sinh(2u)\cosh(2u)dvdu = \frac{\pi}{4}(-1-8\sinh(4)+25\cosh(4))$$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} 8\sin(v)\cos(v)\cosh(2u)^2dvdu = 0$$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} 8u\cosh(2u)^2\sin(v)^2dvdu = -\frac{\pi}{4}(-9-4\sinh(4)+\cosh(4))$$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} -2u\sin(v)\cosh(2u)dvdu = 0$$

So, our result is $\frac{\pi}{4}(-1-8\sinh(4)+25\cosh(4))-\frac{\pi}{4}(-9-4\sinh(4)+\cosh(4))=2\pi+\frac{7\pi}{2e^{4}}+\frac{5\pi e^{4}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I think what @NinadMunshi was getting at was to see S as the boundary of the volume of revolution. (I don't know why they accused you of being disrespectful! - I thought their final comment sounded disrespectful if anything was.) So
$$\int_V\mathrm{d}\omega = \int_S\omega + \text{contributions from top and bottom discs}$$
I'm too lazy to do the actual computations, so will leave them to you (though beware of the signs) ...

Comment: the OP wrote me a (now deleted) comment within two hours of his previous one saying, and I quote, "@NinadMunshi As I suspected, you had no idea how to do this problem in the first place". I am assuming TedShifrin saw the OP's comment when editing his post and upvoted mine, while also declining to answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Okay - thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check all your developments, because it is a super long process, as you said, but here is a quicker way to carry such a computation.

The first step invokes Stokes' theorem in order to transform the surface integral over $S$ into a volume integral over $V$, with $S = \partial V$. One has thus $I := \int_S\omega = \int_V\mathrm{d}\omega$, with $\mathrm{d}\omega = 2\, \mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}y \wedge \mathrm{d}z$, which is nothing else than twice the volume form.

Now, we must choose a parametrization for $V$. The one you gave is based on the cylindrical coordinates with a varying radius; however, it can be simplified a little bit further by recasting it as
$$
V = \{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, r\in[0,2\cosh(2z)], \theta\in[0,2\pi], z\in[0,1]\}.
$$
You already know the volume form expressed in cylindrical coordinates, so that $\mathrm{d}\omega = 2\,\mathrm{dvol}_3 = 2r\, \mathrm{d}r \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta \wedge \mathrm{d}z$ and
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
I &=&\displaystyle
  2\int_{[0,2\cosh(2z)] \times [0,2\pi] \times [0,1]} r\, \mathrm{d}r \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta \wedge \mathrm{d}z \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  8\pi\int_0^1 \cosh^2(2z) \,\mathrm{d}z \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  4\pi\left.\left(z+\frac{1}{4}\sinh(4z)\right)\right|_0^1 \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  \pi(4+\sinh(4))
\end{array}
$$
with the help of the identity $\cosh^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cosh z)$.

Comment: But this is not the correct answer. Clearly, as you stated, $$I:=\int_{S}\omega=\pi(4+\sinh(4))$$ But the correct answer is $$\int_{S}\omega=2\pi+\frac{7\pi}{2e^4}+\frac{5\pi e^4}{2}$$ And these two are not the same answer.

Comment: Is it the solution provided by your professor/book/reference ? Your surface is nothing else than a (rescaled) catenoid, that is the surface of revolution produced by the catenary curve $y = 2\cosh(2x)$, whose volume is a well known result and coincides with mine (see e.g. https://math24.net/volume-solid-of-revolution-disks-washers-page-2.html#example6 for a quick derivation).

Comment: Yes. But my surface has $z\in[0,1]$, so it is not a full catenoid right? That is why you integrate between $0$ and $1$ and the volume is not what you say it is.

Comment: Your surface is half of a catenoid; as it is a symmetric shape, that's just a matter of a factor 2 at the end. In addition, I took the correct interval $[0,1]$ when integrating with respect to $z$; the full catenoid would have lain on $[-1,1]$. Nothing's wrong in my derivation.